# What is the VC-dimension of 4-sided polygon(not convex)?

Tags: geometry, computer-science

It's easy to say that it's at least 9 since convex polygons with k sides have VC-dimension 2k+1, but otherwise I'm stuck with horrible upper bounds in the vicinity of 27 from considering 4 linear classifiers on the plane. Other ways to look at the problem like considering two triangles, touching on the side or convex polygon with triangle cut from it also led me nowhere, so I would really appreciate some help before trying something more exotic since it seems that I'm just missing something relatively trivial.

Comment: What is VC-dimension?

Comment: @N.Owad, in this case it's the maximum amount of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that can be divided in two groups in every possible way by a polygon where one group is the points inside of it and other is the compliment. [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) gives more in depth explanation, albeit more abstract.